# Storage in the blockchain

Tags: storage, blockchain, smartcontracts

I just would like to know more about the storage in blockchain. When a node call a function in a smart contract and pass a string str as a parameter, where this string would be stored?

Does the string stored twice, one in the contract storage ( as programmed in the smart contract ) and one in the chain's block ( as a transaction ) ??

One more thing, does the variables of the smart contract stored as a hashes? I am wondering how the smart contract storage look like ( does it hashes as a transactions in the blocks )

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I just would like to know more about the storage in blockchain. When a
>   node call a function in a smart contract and pass a string str as a
>   parameter, where this string would be stored?

That string would be stored in the tranasction that is generated. However, it dependes on the smart contract that you have installed. Maybe, some smart contract wouldn't save it.

> Does the string stored twice, one in the contract storage ( as
>   programmed in the smart contract ) and one in the chain's block ( as a
>   transaction ) ??

You don't store anything in the contract storage, you only execute the contract. However, Blockchain stores the info twice:

- Ledger: the Ledger stores all the transactions. The ledger is comprised of a blockchain (‘chain’) to store the immutable, sequenced record in blocks. Each node maintains a copy of the ledger.
- State Database: maintains the current state. It represents the latest values for all keys ever included in the chain transaction log. Smart contract invocations execute transactions against the current state data.